# How to construct and reuse networks across two input branches of a network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How to do something like this?

```
nn = get_networks()
A = nn(X_input)
B = nn(X_other_input)
C = A + B
model = ...
```

So that all the tensors in nn are the same, only the input-training branches are different?

In pure tensorflow you do this with

```
tf.variable_scope('something', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
       define stuff here
```

and carefully naming your layers.

But basically you can construct nn in the first place because you can not pass a non-called layer to a layer **call**!

For example:

```
In [21]: tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8))
...
AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

**UPDATE:**

I have been accomplishing this by creating an uncompiled model as the sub-network. That "model" can then be passed to other network creation functions. For example, if you have a functionaly equation that you want to solve, you might approximate the function with a network and then pass the network to the function which is itself a network.

Comment: Am currently trying to just turn the sub-network into a Model with no compile or loss. That seems to allow me to at least feed things in. No idea yet if that is the "correct" approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you would like to reuse it, but the idea is to save your layers once initialized, and use them multiple times later.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import numpy as np

layers = {}

def net1(input):
    layers["l1"] = keras.layers.Dense(10)
    layers["l2"] = keras.layers.Dense(10)

    return layers["l1"](layers["l2"](keras.layers.Flatten()(input)))

def net2(input):
    return layers["l1"](layers["l2"](keras.layers.Flatten()(input)))

input1 = keras.layers.Input((2, 2))
input2 = keras.layers.Input((2, 2))

model1 = keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=net1(input1)) 
model1.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())

model2 = keras.Model(inputs=input2, outputs=net2(input2)) 
model2.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, (50, 2, 2))
m1 = model1.predict(x)
m2 = model2.predict(x)
print(x[0])
print(m1[0])
print(m2[0])
```

Outputs are identical:

```
[ 10.114908  -13.074531   -8.671929  -59.03201    55.389366    1.3610549
 -38.051434    8.355987    7.5310936 -27.717983 ]
[ 10.114908  -13.074531   -8.671929  -59.03201    55.389366    1.3610549
 -38.051434    8.355987    7.5310936 -27.717983 ]
```

Comment: Ah! See you are not actually constructing the network until you have the inputs. What about complex graph structures? Basically this method means you need to store the uncalled layers in a python graph of your choosing and instantiate everything when you actually have the inputs avail. 

You can not __call__ the layers together and then hand in the inputs because the layer __call__ only accepts a "called" layer. 

Would be interesting to see if there is another approach or if I actually get the Model approach to work.

Comment: To be clear, what if this line "l2(l1(keras.layers.Flatten()(input1)))" is 1000 thousands lines of complex graph consructions.

Comment: What is about net construction process that has to happen before you create the inputs? I mean, in your current formulation you can move construction code into a function(s) and save your constructed layers in shared variables.

Comment: Try it. You will find you can not actually combine the layer in the function. You can not *call* them. So if you have a complicated structure, you need to implement your own graph mechanism that stores the pre-call layers no?

Is there some obvious way to do this (store the edges in the graph) that doesn't involved writing something special?

Comment: I edited the answer, but I suspect that it is not what you are looking for either.

Comment: When you say *call* what you are referring to is constructing a tensor. Initializing a layer it only creates a description of how it should look like, while calling it creates an actual operation. Calling layers multiple times would create multiple tensors depending on the same variables. Just as in pure tensorflow, if a tensor (to be constructed by calling a layer) depends on an input in form of another tensor (i.e. input, variable) it would be impossible to create it without providing one. I hope it helps at least a little bit

Comment: No, there is a graph that can be defined *independent* of the input data. I'm sure it can be done in vanilla tensorflow. Keras just hides the placeholder from you. Using an "empty" keras model on recursive layers seems to fool keras into at least running. I'm not 100% sure the weights are being shared properly.